# How to rename columns based on a named list?

Tags: r

I'm looking to rename columns in my data.frame from another list.
Here's my example :

```
mylist <- list(
  var1 = "toto",
  var2 = "titi"
)

mytable <- data.frame(
  var1 = letters[1:3],
  var2 = letters[4:6],
  var6 = letters[7:9]
)
```

I tried that but without success :

```
names(mytable) <- sapply(names(mytable), function(x) mylist$x)
```

Expected result :

```
names(mytable) <- c("toto","titi","var6")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `match` on the names of the `list` and the data.frame to get the index and use that to subset the column names and assign the values of 'mylist'

```
i1 <- match(names(mylist), names(mytable))
names(mytable)[1:2] <- unlist(mylist)
```

-output

```
> mytable
  toto titi var6
1    a    d    g
2    b    e    h
3    c    f    i
```

---

Or with `rename_with`

```
library(dplyr)
mytable %>% 
  rename_with(~ unlist(mylist), all_of(names(mylist)))
  toto titi var6
1    a    d    g
2    b    e    h
3    c    f    i
```

In addition, if the list was constructed with key/value pairs inverted, we could use `!!!` with `rename`

```
library(hash)
mytable %>%
  rename(!!!as.list(invert(hash(mylist))))
  toto titi var6
1    a    d    g
2    b    e    h
3    c    f    i
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `data.table`

```
data.table::setnames(mytable, names(mylist), unlist(mylist))
# mytable
#   toto titi var6
# 1    a    d    g
# 2    b    e    h
# 3    c    f    i
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R:

```
colnames(mytable)[1:length(unname(unlist(mylist)))] <- unname(unlist(mylist))

mytable

  toto titi var6
1    a    d    g
2    b    e    h
3    c    f    i
```